# HashValue mis match in PayUMoney framework, iOS - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, payumoney, payu

I got error like Hash value Mismatch from PayUMoney payment gateway

[image]

Here is my code which I did, please let me know where is issue

```
PUMTxnParam *txnParam= [[PUMTxnParam alloc] init];
//Set the parameters
txnParam.phone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"mobile"];
txnParam.email = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"username"];
txnParam.amount = _txtCash.text;
txnParam.environment = PUMEnvironmentProduction;
txnParam.firstname = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"name1"];
txnParam.key = @"xxxxxxxx";
txnParam.merchantid = @"xxxxxxx";
txnParam.txnID = [txnData valueForKey:@"txnid"];
txnParam.surl = @"https://google.com/";
txnParam.furl = @"https://google.com/";
txnParam.productInfo = @"My App";
txnParam.udf1 = @"";
txnParam.udf2 = @"";
txnParam.udf3 = @"";
txnParam.udf4 = @"";
txnParam.udf5 = @"";
txnParam.hashValue = [self createSHA512:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@|%@||||||%@|",txnParam.key,txnParam.txnID,txnParam.amount,txnParam.productInfo,txnParam.firstname,txnParam.email,txnParam.udf1,txnParam.udf2,txnParam.udf3,txnParam.udf4,txnParam.udf5,@"dxltF25QEp"]];

-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string
{
    const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:string.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
   for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}
```

Please help to clear this out.

Comment: Checkout the parameters name : are those proper or not? as well as keys and all?

Comment: @ShivamTripathi yes all params and keys are as per PayU SDK

Comment: mail to their support team. They will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa pods and Github have their old libraries,
I just copied the library from their example which is in GitHub and it works fine :)